# What is this component called?

Tags: iphone

http://itunes.apple.com/app/bloomberg/id281941097?mt=8

On the second screenshot or this Bloomberg iPhone app..

Can anyone tell me what is the component just above the TABBAR, which shows 
(Bloomberg                  Last Updated: 22:40) called. I don't think so there is such component or may be i don't know.

Or if you can tell me how to create one that would be very helpful

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it is just a standatd UIView with gradient background and 2 labels to display text in different colors and alignment... May be there's some border drawing there as well

There's a lot of resources in customizing iphone UI. Read  [Quartz drawing guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) for drawing basics. The recent ones come to the mind - [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/) is posting a series of tutorials on core graphics now.

I think there're relevant sections in video courses available on itunes - from [Stanford University](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewiTunesUCollection?id=384233225) or [from Brad Larson](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).  etc etc...

Comment: Do you have any good links or tutorials on Styling the iPhone UI..?